# Problem with empty spaces when executing shell commands in AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript

The following code to purge a directory recursively does not work because I cannot get past the **Application Support** folder.

```
try
    do shell script "rm -r ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Pepper Data/Shockwave Flash"
end try
```

- If I use `~/Library/Application Support/Google...` nothing happens. Which is expected.
- If I use `~/Library/Application\ Support/Google...` I cannot save the script due to the error message: `Syntax Error Expected “"” but found unknown token.`

How can I work around this error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
set pathwithSpaces to "/Users/John/Desktop/This is a test.docx"
do shell script "rm -r " & quoted form of pathwithSpaces
```

Answer (score 13):

You have to double the backslashes and also escape the other spaces:

```
do shell script "rm -r ~/Library/Application\\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Pepper\\ Data/Shockwave\\ Flash"
```

or escape the path some other way:

```
do shell script "rm -r ~/'Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Pepper Data/Shockwave Flash'"
```

`quoted form of` replaces `'` with `'\''` and surrounds the string with single quotes, so it doesn't work with paths that start with `~/`.

Answer (score 6):

```
do shell script "open -n /Applications/App\\ Store.app"
```

Handle the `space` with `\\`.

For example replace `App Store.app` with `App\\ Store.app`.